# How to add buy/sell market on a long/short Bollinger Bands graph in python?

Tags: programming, quant-trading-strategies, technical-analysis

I am using `python`, `pandas`, `matplotlib` to do the following:

I have plotted some stock data with it's [Bollinger bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollinger_Bands). The data plotted is `lower_BB`, `upper_bb`, and `df_data`.

- `lower_bb` is a data frame containing the lower Bollinger band data
- `upper_bb` is a data frame containing the upper Bollinger band data.
- `df_data` is a data frame containing data for one stock.

The plot is coming out correctly, but now I want to add vertical lines on my graph where I go long or short a stock. I am slightly confused as how I should do this?

I want to long a stock if the df_data goes upward through the lower bollinger band and I want to short a stock if the df_data drops below the upper bollinger band. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: I'll let the community decide, but to me this is quite off-topic because it's a question you should ask from an abstract point of view on [se], you'd have a better probability to get an answer.

Comment: The general idea though, would be to compute the point where you take the position before you plot the graph, and then add the lines on your lines at the correct index. The graph won't be doing it for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about quantitative finance within the scope of this site.